# Open modal content from a link on another page

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Morning, 
Can anyone shed any light on where I'm going wrong here please? I'm trying to anchor an image on index.html to modal content on mainportfolio.html. My link on index.html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<a href="mainportfolio2.html#portfolioModal93">
<img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="img/homePage/700x450image.png"></a>
</div>
```

And I want that to open this, which is on mainportfolio2.html:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal93" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Image</h2>
                            <p class="item-intro text-muted">Example text</p>
                            <p>More example text</p>
                            <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/image1.jpg" alt="">                      
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Window</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, all that happens is that you're redirected to the top of the portfolio page. I've tried adding the full url to the link on index.html, which didn't work, and I've tried a forwards slash between 
"mainportfolio2.html/#portfolioModal93"
Which serves up a 404 error. This seems like it should be very simple and yet I can't figure it out.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a Bootstrap modal is a javascript event. You'd need to add some javascript to detect that the page should open the modal, and then to actually open the modal.

#### index.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="http://test.dev/mainportfolio2.html#portfolioModal93">
        <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="img/homePage/700x450image.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

#### mainportfolio2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal93" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <div class="lr">
                        <div class="rl">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h2>Image</h2>
                                <p class="item-intro text-muted">Example text</p>
                                <p>More example text</p>
                                <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/image1.jpg" alt="">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Window</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // get the current URL
            var url = $(location).attr('href');

            // if the URL ends with the anchor #portfolioModal93 then we want to open the modal
            if(url == 'http://test.dev/mainportfolio2.html#portfolioModal93') {
                $('#portfolioModal93').modal('show');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for looking at this. I've tried to implement that code you gave me but it still isn't working. Mainportfolio.html already has JS and jQuery links, as I can open any of the 93 modals from clicking the images on that page. I still have the same problem when trying to access the modals on main portfolio.html from the link on index.html. I think I'll copy the code from the modals in main portfolio.html into index and try it that way. Thanks again

Comment: What I gave you works; and answers your question. So your problem must be elsewhere.